# Section floating out of document flow and footer filling half of webpage

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a mock design from online but having 2 issues:

1. The ladies section of code floating out of document flow.
2. footer filling half of page for some reason.

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>The Gym - Personal training</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.blueberry.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(window).load(function() {
        $('.blueberry').blueberry();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <header>

        <a href="#" class="logo"></a>

        <nav>
            <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Trainers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Plans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facility</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>          
            </ul>
        </nav>    

    </header>

    <div id="doc">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="blueberry">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li><img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/inside-gym.png"></li>
                    <li><img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/push-ups.png"></li>
                    <li><img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/chest-fly.png"></li>
                    <li><img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/training.png"></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <section>
        <img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/trainers.png">
        <h1>Best Trainers around</h1>
        <p>eddkjncnljdn ndjqeswndjswndsqwnd id dj oe dnf klenflefewn fewf kewf efe foewn fklenf  lejewf lew nfenf nf enfn feweofjewjfpewjfpjefjewpfjpoewjpf pojfewfjpewfjewjfpoewf;ewkjfpoewj ffjpof jpewfewfp po fpoewjf pokjefkewkf</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/location.png">
        <h1>Local & Convenient</h1>
        <p>eddkjncnljdn ndjqeswndjswndsqwnd id dj oe dnf klenflefewn fewf kewf efe foewn fklenf  lejewf lew nfenf nf enfn feweofjewjfpewjfpjefjewpfjpoewjpf pojfewfjpewfjewjfpoewf;ewkjfpoewj ffjpof jpewfewfp po fpoewjf pokjefkewkf</p>
    </section>

     <section>
        <img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/check.png">
        <h1>Check Us Out - Free</h1>
        <p>eddkjncnljdn ndjqeswndjswndsqwnd id dj oe dnf klenflefewn fewf kewf efe foewn fklenf  lejewf lew nfenf nf enfn feweofjewjfpewjfpjefjewpfjpoewjpf pojfewfjpewfjewjfpoewf;ewkjfpoewj ffjpof jpewfewfp po fpoewjf pokjefkewkf</p>
    </section>

    <article>
        <img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/gym-classes.jpg">
    </article>

    <aside>
        <h2>Our group class schedule:</h2>
        <ul class="gym">
            <li><h3>Studio cycling at 8 am - 60 minutes</h3></li>
            <li><h3>Abs sculpting at 12pm - 30 mins</h3></li>
            <li><h3>Power Yoga at 10 am- 60 minutes</h3></li>
            <li><h3>Boot Camp at 2 pm - 30 minutes</h3></li>
            <li><h3>Butt Sculpting at 4 pm - 60minutes</h3></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>

    <section>
        <h1>Ladies Section</h1>
        <img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/ladies-gym.jpg">
        <p>eddkjncnljdn ndjqeswndjswndsqwnd id dj oe dnf klenflefewn fewf kewf efe foewn fklenf  lejewf lew nfenf nf enfn feweofjewjfpewjfpjefjewpfjpoewjpf ewkjfpoewj ffjpof jpewfewfp po fpoewjf pokjefkewkf</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h1>The Gym Floor</h1>
        <img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/gym-floor.jpg">
        <p>eddkjncnljdn ndjqeswndjswndsqwnd id dj oe dnf klenflefewn fewf kewf efe foewn wfpjefjewpfjpoewjpf pojfewfjpewfjewjfpoewf;ewkjfpoewj ffjpof jpewfewfp po </p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h1>Free Weights</h1>
        <img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/free-weights.jpg">
        <p>eddkjncnljdn ndjqeswndjswndsqwnd id dj oe dnf klenflef pojfewfjpewfjewjfpoewf;ewkjfpoewj ffjpof jpewfewfp po fpoewjf pokjefkewkf</p>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <section>
            <h3><b>The Gym</b></h3>
            <p><b>215-555-5555</b></p> <br><br>
            <p>1700 Chestnut Street<br> Philadelphia, Pa 19100<br>trainer@thegym.com</p>
        </section>

        <section>
            <h3>Connect With Us!</h3>
            <ul class="social">
                <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/facebook1.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/googleplus.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/twitter1.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/youtube1.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>

        <section>
            <img src = "http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/weight-lifter.png">
        </section>

    </footer>

    <footer class="footer-second">
        <p>Copyright- The Gym, 2014</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>


*{
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    font: 14px/20px Arial, Sans-Serif;
    color: #555;
    margin: 0;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size:180%;
    line-height: 120%;
}

h2{
    text-decoration: underline;
    line-height:280%;
    padding-left:2%;
}

h3{
    line-height:110%;
    padding: 5% 0;
}

p{
    padding:1%;
}

img{
    text-align: center;
    max-width:100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
}

a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

header{
    background-color: #405580;
    width: 100%;
    height: 86px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:100;
    opacity: 0.90;
}

.logo {
    margin:20px;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url('http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/the-gym.png') no-repeat center;
    }

nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 35px 20px 20px 0;
}

#menu-icon{
    display: hidden;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url('http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png'); 
}

a:hover#menu-icon{
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
}

.current {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#doc{
    margin: 40px 0;    
}

#content{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1140px;
}

.blueberry {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-top: 110px;
}

section {
    width: 29%;
    float: left;
    margin: 2% 2%;
}

article {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 4%;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 35%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 3%;
}

ul.gym li {
    padding-left:3%;
}

footer{
    background-color: #333333;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.90;
}

footer p, footer h3 {
    color: #fff;
}

footer p a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Clearfix*/

#logo:after, nav:after, nav ul li:after, section:after, article:after, aside:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

I have included the whole code as I don't really know which part could be causing the issue (I assume  but this tag is used throughout the code). Hopefully you guys can help rectify this and explain why this happens.Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Using `float` removes the element from the normal flow of the page. See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float). That'll help with your first problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "float : left" css for the section this will fix both the problems

Comment: Hi. Yes but I need the float left as it's keeping all sections in their position. The only section out of position is <h1>Ladies Section</h1> section. I tried section:after{clear: both; content: ""; display:block;} but this didn't seem to work. Any other solution that might be possible?